# bitwise flag Ops in composition to identify state

Tags: javascript, typescript

for example , there are flags`A,B,C,D` and assign them in bitwise value:

```js
let A=1
let B=1<<1
let C=1<<2
let D=1<<3

let state = A|C|D
let state2 = A|D
```

I want to know how to identify a state with A but without B and C.

I tried the code `state&(A|~C|~D)//get 1101&(0001|1011|0111)=> 1101`  but don't know how to explain the results, maybe this result cannot help me to identify the state.

So what kind of bitwise operations can help me identify the state?

Answer (score 1):

```js
// mask relevant bits, then check
(state & (A|B|C)) == A
```